# Negative question; what's the affirmative answer here?

Tags: questions, negation

My wife and I communicate in English. She's Japanese, I'm Norwegian and we're both language enthusiasts; this makes for a lot of interesting language discussions.

This is something that surfaced today:

> ***"Is this not so good anymore?"***, says my wife, holding up an old container of barbecue sauce which she thinks has gone bad.
>   ***"Yes"***, I answer, meaning that the sauce has gone bad.

Disregarding that ***a)*** the question could probably have been formulated in a different way to make it less ambiguous and ***b)*** I could have been more verbose in my answer; would answering *"Yes"* or *"No"* to this question, in English, indicate that the sauce has, indeed, expired?

Both of our native languages handle these kinds of "negative questions" a bit differently and we can't seem to figure it out in English.

Comment: Single-word answers to negative questions are almost always ambiguous this way, so the safest strategy is to say something like _Yes, it's not so good anymore_, or _No, it's not so good anymore_, depending on how you like to do it. Then the interjection doesn't have to bear so much responsibility alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky! I can see why you would get confused.

First of all your wife's question should be reformulated as: "Has this sauce gone off?"(UK) or "Has this sauce gone bad?"(US) to which your answer: "Yes" would be unequivocal.

However, when a question is **negative interrogative** it is usual to reply positively to confirm the speaker's suspicion/doubt. For example: "**Isn't he** married?" the answer: "Yes, he is" confirms the fact the subject is married. "No, he isn't" means he is single. If however, the question was: "Is he **not married**?" The speaker is asking a completely different question, it is no longer a negative interrogative question but whether the man is single/unmarried, hence the short positive reply would be contradicting as in: Yes, he is (married)!.

So to go back to your wife's original "question" 
"Is this (sauce) not good?" OR "Isn't this (sauce) good?" The first question is not technically a "*negative question*" She was asking if the sauce was bad (not good) so your reply: "Yes (it is)" was actually saying the opposite!

http://www.englishspark.com/en/students/455-negative-questions
http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv330.shtml

Comment: I think you're onto something here, but I would have interpreted “Is he not married?” “Yes” to mean that he is _not_ married. Maybe. It's ambiguous.

Comment: "Is he not married?" The answer: "Yes" tells us the opposite, you are contradicting the speaker's suspicion. lets try another example: "Are you not happy?" if you reply: "Yes, I am!" you are telling the speaker he is wrong in making that assumption. That's how I interpret it... but I admit it is making my head spin a little!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I accepted it because I think you're onto something and the links explained even more. I would also agree with Bradd Szonye and interpreted a "Yes" to the question "Is he not married?" to mean "Yes, he is not married", and a "Yes" to the question "Are you not happy?" to mean "Yes, I am not happy."

Comment: For “Are you not happy?” I would interpret the response more according to tone than _yes_ or _no._

Comment: This stuff is so confusing :p

Comment: I think part of the problem stems from the single word response: "Yes". As @John Lawler correctly pointed out, yes, weirdly, is too ambiguous. Personally, I would mentally add "Yes, **he is**" to make the response more complete but I can see how many would opt for: "Yes, **he is not married**."